# Rails 3 Adding additional join relationship fails to set primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, model-associations, join

I have four tables with the below associations and a nested form that correctly creates and saves one record of each model. After adding one additional level of nesting to include a new join model, my form fails to save due to the fact that company_id is not getting set on the Contact model.

Original working models:

Company:

```
Company < ActiveRecordBase
attr_accessible :companyContacts_attributes, :company_name, :created_by, :import_path,    :is_active, :is_tracker_client, :tracker_code, :tracker_import_path, :updated_by,
:locations_attributes, :contacts_attributes

has_many :locations, dependent: :destroy # A company has one or more locations
has_many :addresses, through: :locations
has_many :contacts

accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
accepts_nested_attributes_for :contacts
```

Location:

```
Location < ActiveRecordBase
    attr_accessible  :address_attributes, :address, :created_by, :is_active, :location_name, :location_type_id, :region_id, :updated_by, :website

belongs_to :company
belongs_to :address
accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, :reject_if => :all_blank
```

Address:

```
Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible  :address_line_1, :address_line_2, :address_line_3, :address_line_4, :address_line_5, :city, :country, :county, :created_by, :province, :state, :updated_by, :zipcode 

has_many :locations, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :companies, through: :location
```

Contact:

```
Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :company_id, :created_by, :first_name, :is_active, :last_name, :title, :updated_by

belongs_to :company
```

Now I'd like to add a join table, CompanyContact, that links a Company, Location, and Contact. This table simply has company_id, location_id and contact_id

CompanyContact:

```
CompanyContact < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :location_attributes, :location, :contact_attributes, :company, :contact,  :created_by, :is_active, :updated_by

belongs_to :company
belongs_to :contact
belongs_to :location

accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact, :reject_if => :all_blank
accepts_nested_attributes_for :location, :reject_if => :all_blank
```

I updated my Company models to include the following additional statements:

Company:

```
attr_accessible :companyContacts_attributes

has_many :companyContacts
has_many :locations, through: :companyContacts, dependent: :destroy
has_many :contacts, through: :companyContacts, dependent: :destroy 
accepts_nested_attributes_for :companyContacts
```

Location:

```
has_many :companyContacts
has_one  :company, through: :companyContacts
```

Contacts:

```
has_many :companyContacts
has_one :company, through: :companyContacts
```

I then used fields_for to nest the location and contact form inputs inside the CompanyContact.
Everything looks good except when I save the Transaction rolls back with an error that says:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'company_id', table
>   'TakeBackDBMSConversion.recycle.Contact'; column does not allow nulls.
>   INSERT fails.: EXEC sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO [recycle].[Contact]
>   ([company_id], [created_at], [created_by], [first_name], [is_active],
>   [last_name], [title], [updated_at], [updated_by]) VALUES (@0, @1, @2,
>   @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8); SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS bigint) AS
>   Ident', N'@0 int, @1 datetime, @2 varchar(50), @3 varchar(50), @4 bit,
>   @5 varchar(50), @6 varchar(100), @7 datetime, @8 varchar(50)', @0 =
>   NULL, @1 = '2014-02-13T21:25:09.337', @2 = N'Chris Reid', @3 =
>   N'Sean', @4 = 0, @5 = N'Jackson', @6 = N'CEO', @7 =
>   '2014-02-13T21:25:09.337', @8 = NULL

The params that get passed to the controller look to be nested correctly:

> {"utf8"=>"✓",  "authenticity_token"=>"xxxblahblahblah", 
>   "company"=>{"company_name"=>"A Fake Company", 
>   "companyContacts_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"location_attributes"=>{"address_attributes"=>{"address_line_1"=>"676
>   Fake Ln.",  "address_line_2"=>"",  "address_line_3"=>"", 
>   "city"=>"Mobile",  "state"=>"AL",  "country"=>"USA", 
>   "zipcode"=>"89998"},  "location_type_id"=>"1", 
>   "location_name"=>"Mobile"}, 
>   "contact_attributes"=>{"first_name"=>"Sean",  "last_name"=>"Jackson", 
>   "title"=>"CEO"}}}},  "commit"=>"Save Info"}

Why is the company_id suddenly (meaning now that I've added the CompanyContact association) not available to the contact record? Did I miss something in the way I set up the new associations? I'm at a loss after trying multiple solutions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.